# trouble pulling a value from a dropdown menu in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, this, setstate

this might be a dumb question, but I'm new to react and I'm having some difficulty with my drop-down menu.  Long story short, I've got a list of locations, and I need to be able to 'pull out' whichever location the user picks from the menu (I plan on using that location info to generate a map using Google's static maps API).

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <select className="menu" name="select" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.searchLocations}>
      {options}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

(and this is the code that generates {options}):

```
    let options = this.state.locationsBase.map((item, index) => {
    return(
      <option key={index + 1} value={this.state.locationsBase}>{item.name}</option>
    )
  })
```

locationsBase is an array that's loaded in with componentDidMount.

So my problem is this:
`<select value= >` is returning 'undefined', when I need it to return whichever location the user clicks on (and the values for locations are contained in {options} ).  (also, these locations all show up in the drop-down menu).

I don't know if this is very clear, but any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**update**

this is what the searchLocations function looks like:

```
      searchLocations(e){
       e.preventDefault()
       let selectedLocation = this.locationQuery
       console.log(selectedLocation)
       this.setState({
       locationResults: this.state.selectedLocation
     })
```

`selectedLocation` returns `undefined` in the console.

and `locationQuery` is set to `this.value` in my initial state.

**update (full component):**

```
class LocationsContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
  locationQuery: this.value,
  locationResults: "",
  locationsBase: []
 }


this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this)
this.searchLocations = this.searchLocations.bind(this)
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount(){
this.setState({
  locationsBase:[
    {name: "Pick a branch" , address: ""},
    {name: "Anacostia" , address: "1800 Good Hope Rd SE"},
    {name: "Bellevue" , address: "115 Atlantic St SW"},
    {name: "Benning" , address: "3935 Benning Rd NE"},
    {name: "Capitol View" , address: "5001 Central Ave SE"},
    ]
    }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.locationsBase)
  })
}
  handleOnChange(e) {
  const name = e.target.value
  this.setState({
  [name]: e.target.value
 })
  console.log("name")
}

searchLocations(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let selectedLocation = this.locationQuery
  console.log(selectedLocation)
  this.setState({
    locationResults: this.state.selectedLocation
  })


  console.log(this.locationResults, 'something is working')
  }

handleSubmit(e) {
alert('Your location is: ' + this.state.value);
event.preventDefault();
}



 render (){
  let options = this.state.locationsBase.map((item, index) => {
    return(
      <option key={index + 1} value={this.state.locationsBase}>
      {item.name}</option>
    )
   })

return (
  <div>
    <h3>Choose your branch!</h3>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <select className="menu" name="select" value={this.state.value} 
      onChange={this.searchLocations}>
      {options}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>



    <p>{this.state.locationResults}</p>

  </div>

  )
}


 }


export default LocationsContainer
```

Comment: what does your `this.searchLocations` function look like? It should be updating `this.state.value`.  That way you can just grab `this.state.value` whenever you need the selected value

Comment: Could you show how you handle your state? Also your `option` value shouldn't be the same array...

Comment: @StephenL I've updated the post to include the searchLocations function.

Comment: @BravoZulu do you mean my default state?

Comment: shouldn't it be `let selectedLocation = this.state.locationQuery`? It looks like you have a couple of problems in your code, maybe post the full component?

Comment: Update `onChange={this.searchLocations}` to `onChange={this.searchLocations.bind(this)}` to ensure your `this` corresponds to the correct scope.

Comment: @BravoZulu  full component is up.  thank you so much for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to pass the onChange event to the searchLocations function.

```
    <select onChange={( e ) => this.searchLocations( e ) }>
      {options}
    </select>
```

Then grab the value at `e.target.value` and pass that to your `this.locationQuery` function.

Hope this helps!